# Django-allauth - How do I get the form errors from Ajax?

Tags: django, django-allauth

Using django-allauth, how do I obtain form errors via AJAX login?

I am using this view with my `/signup/` url:

```
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
```

Conveniently, it accepts my Ajax call:

```
var signupForm = function(token) {
   $.ajax({ url:"/signup/",
            type:"POST",
            data: {
                "email": $('#user').val(),
                "password1": $('#pass1').val(),
                "password2": $('#pass2').val()
            },
           success: function (){
                location.href = '/';
                window.location.reload(true);
           },
            error:function (er) {
                alert("signup failure...",er);
            }
        });
};
```

Inconveniently, if there is a problem with the form, it returns:

> error 400: Bad Request

This gives me no idea why a login has failed. I would like to be able to convey to the user what happened. Was it a problem with her password? Was her email address already registered?

Can I accomplish this with all-auth, or do I need to write my own validation from javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a supported solution, so I hacked it:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from allauth.account.views import SignupView, _ajax_response

class AjaxSignUpView(SignupView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = self.form_valid(form)
            return _ajax_response(
                self.request, response, form=form, data=self._get_ajax_data_if())
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'errors': form.errors})
```

Comment: Please, I just found your post it seems correct except that now I want to manage as you login and registration via a modal (Bootstrap) ajax and also have control over some context variables . Your answer suits me but only it is incomplete and above all you do not say how we could do it for Login view. Could you post for me a more complete answer for registration and login via ajax (for Django allauth of course)? Please...

Comment: What other information are you looking for? You can use the exact same code for `LoginView`. This will send the errors back in a json object to the Ajax routine.

Comment: good luck uncle! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that it is missing the `csrfmiddlewaretoken`. You should include it in the form (with the tag `{% csrf_token %}`) and then add it to your AJAX request like this:

```
$.ajax({ url:"/signup/",
        type:"POST",
        data: {
            "email": $('#user').val(),
            "password1": $('#pass1').val(),
            "password2": $('#pass2').val(),
            "csrfmiddlewaretoken": $('<selector for the csrf token input>').val()
        },
        ...
```

this item is required for all `POST` requests in django.

Comment: I have another working method of delivering the CSRF cookie, but thanks for looking out!