# Django - how to return JSON responses instead of HTML during authentication?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm in the process of building a Vue SPA that will use the standard Django Session Authentication since the Django app and the Vue app will be on the same server and same domain.

I've always used [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) for everything authentication-related, but the problem, in this case, is that authentication is not handled by Django templates, but I use AJAX to send POST requests to Django to register, sign in, and everything else.

Is there any way to make Django-Allauth or Django send JSON responses instead of standard HTML and redirects?

Here is an example POST request from my code that i use to login:

```
bodyFormData.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', this.csrf_token)
bodyFormData.append('login', 'root');
bodyFormData.append('password', 'Stest');

axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/",
  data: bodyFormData,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
})
.then(function (response) {
  //handle success
})
.catch(function (response) {
  //handle error
});
```

And [here is the login view:](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/views.py)

```
class LoginView(
    RedirectAuthenticatedUserMixin, AjaxCapableProcessFormViewMixin, FormView
):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "account/login." + app_settings.TEMPLATE_EXTENSION
    success_url = None
    redirect_field_name = "next"

    @sensitive_post_parameters_m
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(LoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs["request"] = self.request
        return kwargs

    def get_form_class(self):
        return get_form_class(app_settings.FORMS, "login", self.form_class)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        try:
            return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Explicitly passed ?next= URL takes precedence
        ret = (
            get_next_redirect_url(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
            or self.success_url
        )
        return ret

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(
            self.request, reverse("account_signup"), self.redirect_field_name
        )
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update(
            {
                "signup_url": signup_url,
                "site": site,
                "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value,
            }
        )
        return ret
```

This seems to work fine, it logs me in but the response is HTML and from the network tabs I can see that Django tries to redirect me to another page (because that's what it does when authentication is handled by Django templates).

Is there any way I can make it send only JSON responses? Do I have to override some view or am I forced to change the code of the library? Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Better to use `django-rest-framework` here.

Comment: The problem is that DRF doesn't have a library that offers the same features as Django-Allauth

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/61733237/2830850, https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/658,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly looked through the code of django-allauth.
I see one opportunity that may put you in the right direction?

django-allauth allows you to set your own adapter.

For example if you have an app called "my_applabel" and place a file custom_adapter.py with the following class and inherit the [DefaultAccountAdapter](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/353386216b79f16709e97bb487c0bbbba2bc0c71/allauth/account/adapter.py):

```
class MyOwnAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def ajax_response(self, request, response, redirect_to=None, form=None, data=None):
        # Craft your own response.
```

in settings try ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'my_applabel.custom_adapter.MyOwnAdapter'

see docs [ACCOUNT_ADAPTER](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)

It gives opportunity to override certain behaviours/methods from the DefaultAccountAdapter.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This worked. I'm trying to see if i can do it from the view too

Answer (score -1):

You can use drf with djoser for it. It will give you to work with as usual token and also with jwt tokens for authorization, i think it will more better than using django template such way

Comment: Thank you, but in this case i want to use Session Authentication, with JWT tokens i would have problems with security such as where to store the token