# Express body-parser req.body with formdata is empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, form-data, body-parser

Somehow my req.body is always empty, maybe you have an idea:

here is my server code:

```
const Express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = new Express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)  // => {}
  res.send(req.body);
});

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
app.listen(3000, err => {
   if (err) { return console.error(err); }
   console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

When I try to send formdata with javascript the req.body is empty:

```
const data = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
console.log(data);  // seems empty already??? FormData{}??
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/save');
xhr.send(data);
```

Same with postman:

[image: postman]

I don’t understand this…

Sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` with postman or `raw (application/json)` works in postman. But sending the same headers with Formdata in javascript will still result in an empty object…

Comment: `body-parser` doesn't support form-data, you need [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) or something similar.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542586/new-formdata-application-x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To log every field in formData

```
let myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
formData = new FormData(myForm);

for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/thesumit67/j4znhxa5/1/

To handle it via express use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).
Here is an example - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Make sure to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on form element. Otherwise Multer will ignore it.

```
let multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer();

app.post('/save', upload.fields([]), (req, res) => {
  console.log( req.body );
  console.log( req.files );
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days now, this doesn't seem to work for me. The body is still empty.

Comment: @Muganwas change the upload.fields into upload.single("keyname")

Answer (score 11):

body-parser is deprecated and isn't a part of Express anymore.

Also, body-parser does not provide the functionality to parse form-data post data.

From the body-parser repository [description](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature. For multipart bodies, you may be interested in the following modules:

- [busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/busboy#readme) and
  [connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-busboy#readme)
- [multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multiparty#readme) and
  [connect-multiparty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-multiparty#readme)
- [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable#readme)
- [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer#readme)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the problem may be in the HTML form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="foo[bar]">
 <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in the server code it may look something like this.

```
 app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body.foo)  // => {}
 res.send(req.body.foo);
});
```

Again, this post is older so you've probably already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, I was using the fetch api, sending form data to an node.js/express backend. The problem was that I had set `enctype='multipart/form-data'` on the form and I was also setting `Content-type: multipart/form-data` in the fetch Headers.
Removing the `Content-type` from the Headers got everything to work.
I got the solution from here => https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/411

Answer (score 0):

Use multer, but I'd like to mention that formidable can also be used for this. Ideally this should be an express middleware though.

```
import formidable, { Fields } from 'formidable';

function getFormData(request: express.Request): Promise<Fields> {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        form.parse(request, function(error: Error, fields: Fields) {
            if (error !== null) {
                reject(error);
            }

            resolve(fields);
        })
    });
}

app.post('/foo', async (request: express.Request, response: express.Response): Promise<void> => {
    const formData = await getFormData(request);
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Express and body parser Version :

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); 
app.use( bodyParser.json()); 

const baseUrl = '/api/v1/tours';
app.post(baseUrl, (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Done');
})
//starting server
const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`app running on port ${port}...`);
});
```

To send raw data please select JSON from the list 
[image]