# Trying to send form data to Express app, can't parse into req.body correctly

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, form-data, body-parser

I know that a similar question has been asked many times, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861517/express-body-parser-req-body-with-formdata-is-empty-object).

However, I've tried applying various solutions from these answers without success.

Here's my client-side page:

```
<form id="submit_newuser" method="POST" action="/submit_newuser">
    User name:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    <br>
    Phone number:
    <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("submit_newuser").addEventListener('submit',submit_newuser);

function submit_newuser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    submit_newuserForm=document.getElementById("submit_newuser");
    formData=new FormData(submit_newuserForm);
    fetch("/submit_newuser",{
        body:formData,
        headers:{
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method:"post"
    })
    .then(response=>console.log(response))
    .catch(err=>"submit_newuser: error: "+err);
}
</script>
```

And here's the relevant server-side code for the `/submit_newuser` endpoint:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/submit_newuser',function(req,res){
    console.log("/submit_newuser: req.body: "+JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var phonenumber=req.body.phonenumber;
    var username=req.body.username;
    var output="you submitted: "+username+" "+phonenumber;
    console.log("/submit_newuser: text to send back: "+output);
    res.send(output);
});
```

With this, when I submit data from the page, the server logs this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
```

When I change the Content-Type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", I get this console logging:

```
/submit_newuser: req.body: {"------WebKitFormBoundaryBDU4OcntAv7d5wWL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name":"\"username\"\r\n\r\ntestUserName\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryBDU4OcntAv7d5wWL\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"phonenumber\"\r\n\r\ntestPhoneNumber\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryBDU4OcntAv7d5wWL--\r\n"}

/submit_newuser: text to send back: you submitted: undefined undefined
```

Which indicates that the data is being posted to the server, but not properly parsed into `req.body`.

Solutions involving `multer` don't seem to apply here because I'm not uploading a file, but I'm not sure if I should nonetheless be using a different approach than posting a `FormData` object in the `fetch()` body.

I'm confused, and also wondering if there's a simpler way to do this.  I just want to post form data to the server without triggering a page refresh, and be able to update page elements with the server response.

Comment: When you use FormData then the content-type should be `multipart/form-data` not a json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your client-side code to send a JSON body like so, this will be parsed correctly by the server.

Because we're setting the content-type header to JSON on the client, we must send JSON data. We could send url encoded data or multipart/form-data, however we would have to change headers on the client to do this.

```
document.getElementById("submit_newuser").addEventListener('submit',submit_newuser);

function formDataToJson(formData) {
    const obj = {};
    formData.forEach((value, key) => { 
        obj[key] = value
    });
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
}

function submit_newuser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    submit_newuserForm=document.getElementById("submit_newuser");
    formData = new FormData(submit_newuserForm);
    fetch("/submit_newuser",{
        body: formDataToJson(formData),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        method:"post"
    })
    .then(response=>console.log(response))
    .catch(err=>"submit_newuser: error: "+err);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send client's request as formData then you must handle your backend-side to receive request as formData.

There is a npm module called [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for handling formData request type.

Anyway your code must change to something like this:

**Client-side**

```
<script>

 document.getElementById("submit_newuser").addEventListener('submit',submit_newuser);

  function submit_newuser(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    submit_newuserForm=document.getElementById("submit_newuser");
    formData=new FormData(submit_newuserForm);
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit_newuser",{
        body:formData,
        method:"post"
    })
    .then(response=>console.log(response))
    .catch(err=>"submit_newuser: error: "+err);
}
</script>
```

**Server-side**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/submit_newuser', upload.none(), function (req, res) {
  console.log("/submit_newuser: req.body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  var phonenumber = req.body.phonenumber;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var output = "you submitted: " + username + " " + phonenumber;
  console.log("/submit_newuser: text to send back: " + output);
  res.send(output);
});
```

Comment: I went with Terry Lenox's approach because I can use it without adding another module.  But I will keep yours in mind if, in the future, I decide to include file uploads in the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Use below sample ajax call for sending data from frontend.

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:3000/submit_newuser",
  "method": "POST",
  "data": {
    "username": "test user",
    "phonenumber": "03453512545"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

sample postman request.

[image]